# Why does $(e^{-\frac{3}{4}t}-e^{it})(\frac{3}{4}-i) = e^{-\frac{3}{4}t}-\cos t+ \frac{3}{4}\sin t$

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, laplace-transform, mathematical-physics

I read this while going through some derivations in my mathematical physics class. I thought of multiplying everything and applying Euler's formula but I don't understand how the $ie^{-\frac{3}{4}t}$ could be turned into something real.

A little more context: this was after doing convolution with the Laplace transform and then doing something with real numbers to solve this deceptively easy-looking problem $y''+y'+\frac{3}{16}y(t) = \sin (t),\quad y(0) = y'(0) = 0$.

Comment: this is false for the reason you mention: the LHS takes on non-real values while the RHS only takes on real values (eg plug in $t=2\pi$). Just expand this out as you normally would (or recheck your earlier calculations).

Answer (score 1):

Your simplification is not correct. use $e^{it}=\cos t+ i\sin t$, then
$$(e^{-3t/4}-\cos t-i \sin t)(\frac{3}{4}-i)=\frac{3}{4} e^{-3t/4}-\frac{3}{4} \cos t- \frac{3i}{4}\sin t-i 3^{-3t/4}-i \cos t  -\sin t.$$